# Add/Insert double AND string into a list

Tags: c#, string, list, double

so, quickly. Is it possible to insert a double AND a string into a list? like this:

```
 if (input2 == 0)  // this boolean checks if the first number is devided by zero, then:
                {
                    listOfResults.Insert(index: temp, item: "You divided by 0! Wait, thats illegal"); // and thats what i want, to add a string into the position of the list when the input is 0
                }
                else
                {
                    result = (double)input1 / (double)input2; // the input numbers are int but i cast them to double 
                    listOfResults.Insert(index: position, item: result);
                }
```

My input are : 3 and 2, 6 and 3, -4 and 0, 1 and 2,  i devide every first number by the second input number.
The output should be like:

1.5
2
You divided by 0! Wait, thats illegal
0.5
So is it possible to store doubles AND string for each position in List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could make a List< object >  which can contain any data type, double, string, int, other objects, etc.

A better option may be to define a Result object such as

```
class Result
{
    public bool Error { get; set; } = false;
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; } = "";
}
```

And then store a list of List< Result > so that you don't need to convert or check types.

Comment: when using List<Object> i try  numWeight = listOfResults[0]; but it says Cannot convert from objct to string. I also try  numWeight= double.Parse(listOfResults[0]); but still no luck, how do i convert objet to double?

Comment: i cast it like (double)listOfResults[count]; and it worked, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

List will allow both types. You can use typeof() == typeof(double), for instance, when using the values, or simply ToString().

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   List<object> myData = new List<object>()
   {
                1.234,
                -0.1,
                "divide by zero",
                100.0
   };

   foreach (object item in myData)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you give me a simple example how could i add several entries in my lest, double, double, string, double? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list of tuples:

```
var tupleList = new List<(double, string)>();
tupleList.Add((2.5, "a string"));
```

Here's what I'd do given your code:

```
var listOfResults = new List<(double? result, string error)>();
if (input2 == 0)
{
    listOfResults.Insert(index: temp, item: (null, "You divided by 0! Wait, thats illegal"));
}
else
{
    result = (double)input1 / input2;
    listOfResults.Insert(index: position, item: (result, null));
}
```

And here's how to print the output:

```
foreach (var item in listOfResults)
{
    if (item.result.HasValue)
        Console.WriteLine(item.result);
    else
        Console.WriteLine(item.error);
}
```

Comment: how this would work with my code? Is it mandatory to put double AND string? You see i need to put double, then string, then double again, how would i do that? Please give me an example. thank you

Comment: @IgorCherkasov Added.